# ¿Cual es la diferencia entre seleccionar por ID o ClassName?

Tags: javascript

¿Por qué si puedo cambiar propiedades del objeto al seleccionarlo con `getElementById`, mientras que si lo selecciono con `getElementByClassName` me marca undefined?

**¿Cuál es la teoría detrás de esto?**

*Pruebas en las consola de Google chrome*
[image: Pruebas en las consola de Google chrome]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La referencia a un elemento del HTML de la página mediante **getElementById** se hace sobre una ID, que por norma debe ser única en esa página, así que da acceso directo a el elemento con esa ID.

Al usar **getElementByClassName** nos referimos a la clase del elemento, siendo posible y frecuente que varios elementos compartan esa clase, por lo que no tenemos acceso directo a un elemento para poder trabajar, sino el conjunto de los elementos con esa clase en la página, por lo que deberemos conocer su orden de aparición para operar sobre el elemento deseado, es decir que obtenemos un array de los elementos de la página con esa clase según su orden de aparición en el *DOM* y debemos indicar la posición en este array para acceder al elemento concreto.

***Nota:*** en ambos casos obtendremos un valor *undefined* si el elemento que intentamos acceder no existe en el DOM, ya sea porque no se encontraba en el HTML desde el principio o se elimino del DOM, antes de intentar el acceso. También tendrás *undefined* si intentas acceder a un elemento del array de resultados cuya posición no existe, es decir que si tienes 3 elementos con la clase "chicharo-magico" en el dom y haces esto: `console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("chicharo-magico")[1000]);`
el resultado es un *undefined*.

> Por lo explicado antes la manipulación de elementos usando IDs es muy
>   usada: identifican al elemento inequívocamente y permiten un acceso
>   directo al mismo.
>
> El acceso mediante clases puede ser útil cuando se quiere aplicar
>   algún cambio o acción a varios elementos simultáneamente o si por el
>   motivo que sea no se pueden usar IDs para manipular el DOM.

Answer (score 2):

Es que getElementsByClassName a diferencia de ById devuelve una coleccion y no un elemento.

deberias hacer:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('algo')[0].style.color='red';
```

o buscar en un bucle for.

Answer (score 0):

El selector `id` es un **identificador único** de un objeto DOM, sin embargo un selector de clase `class`, puede ser aplicado a varios elementos, la manera de manipularlos es similar a una **arreglo**, es decir por posiciones.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('textoClass')[0].style.color='blue';
```

> Solución

```js
document.getElementById('textoID').style.color='red';
            document.getElementsByClassName('textoClass')[0].style.color='blue';
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">

        <span id="textoID">Texto con ID</span>
        <span class="textoClass">Texto con clase</span>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a todos por sus respuestas.
En resumen, el ID es único y no se repite en el documento. Los CLASS crean un array y para acceder a ellos es por orden de apariencia [0] o [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEMfy.jpg) o [2].
Entonces: si quiero modificar todos los elementos con CLASS puedo usar un FOR.

[image: Pruebas en la consola de chrome]