# Problema al cambiar getElements de ID por ClassName

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy intentando que los usuarios puedan cambiar el color principal (`.primary-color`) de mi página, escogiendo entre unos colores preestablecidos.

Encontré este pequeño *snippet*

```js
function change(i) {

  var color = document.getElementById("color");

  color.style.backgroundColor = i;

}
```

```css
.div-1 {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px
}

.div-2 {
  background-color: black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px
}

.div-3 {
  background-color: green;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px
}

.div-4 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px
}

#color {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-1" onclick="change('orange')"></div>
<div class="div-2" onclick="change('black')"></div>
<div class="div-3" onclick="change('green')"></div>
<div class="div-4" onclick="change('red')"></div>

<div id="color"></div>
```

Se presentan 4 colores a escoger para aplicar al quinto DIV. Funciona bien.

Pero si quiero cambiar el quinto DIV, es decir pasar del ID a una clase, no me funciona:

```js
function change(i) {

  var color = document.getElementsByClassName("color");

  color.style.backgroundColor = i;

}
```

```css
.div-1 {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px
}

.div-2 {
  background-color: black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px
}

.div-3 {
  background-color: green;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px
}

.div-4 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px
}

.color {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-1" onclick="change('orange')"></div>
<div class="div-2" onclick="change('black')"></div>
<div class="div-3" onclick="change('green')"></div>
<div class="div-4" onclick="change('red')"></div>

<div class="color"></div>
```

Aquí en el sitio hay un tema similar pero no me quedó del todo claro: [¿Cual es la diferencia entre seleccionar por ID o ClassName?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/179855/cual-es-la-diferencia-entre-seleccionar-por-id-o-classname)

No conozco mucho JS, puede ser un error de tipeo? Muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La diferencia radica en lo que devuelve cada uno de los métodos:

**Por id**

```
document.getElementById("color");
```

La id, al considerarse que debe ser una clave única, devolvería un solo elemento, el que tenga como atributo **id** el valor **color**.

**Por clase**

```
document.getElementsByClassName("color");
```

La clase, al ser una clave que puede darse en múltiples elementos de tu **DOM**, devuelve una colección de todos los elementos que posean dicha clase. Por ello, para poder referenciar a `<div id="color"></div>` deberías hacer:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("color")[0];
```

Con esto accederías al primer elemento que salga en el **DOM** de tu página y que tenga la clase "color". En tu caso, al tener solamente uno estarías referenciándolo correctamente.

**EDIT**

Añado snipped para mayor claridad y uniendo a mi solución la que propuso  @Iñigo Irigoyen Erquicia:

```js
function change(color) {

  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("color");
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].style.backgroundColor=color;
  }
 

}
```

```css
.div-1 {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px
}

.div-2 {
  background-color: black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px
}

.div-3 {
  background-color: green;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px
}

.div-4 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px
}

.color {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-1" onclick="change('orange')"></div>
<div class="div-2" onclick="change('black')"></div>
<div class="div-3" onclick="change('green')"></div>
<div class="div-4" onclick="change('red')"></div>

<div class="color"></div>
<div class="color"></div>
<div class="color"></div>
```

Comment: Sólo debería aplicar ese cambio? Porque no me funciona lamentablemente

Comment: Mis disculpas. Me debió de dar un lapsus mental. Ahora si se encuentra bien referenciado el elemento. El indicador de índice de array [0] debe de ir después de haber seleccionado los elementos de la clase deseada.

Comment: Funciona, pero al ser una clase, se presenta varias veces en el html, si triplico el ultimo div, el indice [0] solo se aplica al 1er div. ¿Cómo hago para que se aplique a todos los elementos que tengan la misma clase?

Comment: Creo que este código podria ayudar: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_element_getelementsbyclassname_loop

Comment: Para hacer eso que dices deberías hacer lo que el compañero Iñigo Irigoyen Erquicia propuso en su respuesta. Un bucle **for** que recorra toda esa colección de elementos (gracias por la corrección @Pablo Lozano) y que les vaya cambiando el color.

Comment: He añadido una edición a mi respuesta para contemplar un caso con múltiples elementos con la clase color.

Comment: Perfecto. Mil gracias Myguel por tu explicacion y tu tiempo

Answer (score 7):

Cuando coges con el nombre de la clase, te coge un array mpor lo que tienes que recorrer los elemntos para poder cambiar el estilo de estos.

```js
function change(colorName) {

  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("color");
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].style.backgroundColor=colorName;
    }
 

}
```

```css
.div-1 {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px
}

.div-2 {
  background-color: black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px
}

.div-3 {
  background-color: green;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px
}

.div-4 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px
}

.color {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-1" onclick="change('orange')"></div>
<div class="div-2" onclick="change('black')"></div>
<div class="div-3" onclick="change('green')"></div>
<div class="div-4" onclick="change('red')"></div>

<div class="color"></div>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, indepedendiente del color que escoga, siempre me pinta de azul. Quisiera saber ¿porqué lo usas en el código JS?

Comment: @AMCode cambia el parámetro que pasas en tu función para que no choque con la variable `i` y ese parámetro ponlo `elements[i].style.backgroundColor= j;`, le puso blue de forma estática.

Comment: hola @Horacio Sanchez las ediciones que se proponen a las respuestas no deben ir en contra del contenido original publicado en las mismas, pues eso se toma como vandalismo, si consideras que quien respondió tiene errores, déjale un comentario aquí pero no le modifiques el código de su aporte

Comment: @VickMuñoz sin funcionar. No debería dar primero un valor a `j`?

Comment: @AMCode `j` es el parámetro que pasas a tu función `change` de esta manera `change(j){...}` la respuesta que hace PHPMyguel lo deja en claro, si te ayudo su respuesta deberías marcarla como aceptada.

Comment: @AMCode Cogí el código que tenías en el segundo fragmento y lo modifiqué para que funcionara, siento no haberte dado toda la solución.

Comment: No tienes porqué Iñigo, muchas gracias a todos ustedes por su tiempo y compartir sus conocimientos. Es muy unida esta comunidad. Les agradezco de verdad de todo corazon